# Finding a First Integral of a System of First-Order DEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, systems-of-equations

> I am trying to show that the system $$\frac{dx_1}{dt}=ax_1, \ \ \frac{dx_2}{dt}=-x_2$$ has a first integral of the form $$K(x_1,x_2)=\ln(f(x_1))+\ln(g(x_2))a$$

My attempt:

I will use the following method.
$$\frac{dx_1}{dt}=ax_1\iff \frac{dx_1}{ax_1}=dt \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$
$$\frac{dx_2}{dt}=-x_2\iff \frac{dx_2}{-x_2}=dt \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)$$
Equating $(1)$ and $(2)$ yields
\begin{align}
\frac{dx_1}{ax_1}&=\frac{dx_2}{-x_2} \\
\frac{1}{a}\ln|x_1|&=-\ln|x_2|+C \\
\ln|x_1|+a\ln|x_2|&=0 \ \ \  \ \ (C=0)
\end{align}
I do not know where to go from here. Is my working correct so far? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $\frac{1}{a}\ln|x_1|=-\ln|x_2|+C$ is equivalent to $\hat{C}=\ln|x_1|+a\ln|x_2|$, where $\hat{C}$ is the first integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is correct. At the line before the end, simply multiply by $a$ and observe :

$$\frac{1}{a}\ln|x_1|=-\ln|x_2|+C \Leftrightarrow aC =\ln|x_1| + a\ln|x_2| $$

$$\implies$$

$$\hat{C} = \ln|x_1| + a\ln|x_2|$$

$$\implies$$

$$C(x_1,x_2) = \ln|x_1| + a\ln|x_2|$$

which is indeed a first integral of the form $K(x_1,x_2)=\ln(f(x_1))+\ln(g(x_2))a$ with $K(x_1,x_2) = C(x_1,x_2), \; f(x_1) = |x_1|, \; f(x_2) = |x_2|$.