# How can I find the first integral of a system of homogeneous first-order linear system of differential equations with constant coefficients?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following homogeneous first-order linear system of differential equations with constant coefficients
\begin{gather*}
\begin{cases}
\dot x_0=3\, x_1\\
  \dot x_1=x_0+2\, x_2,\\
 \dot x_2 =2\, x_1+  x_3,\\
 \dot x_3 =3\, x_{2}.
\end{cases}
\end{gather*}

I need to find **the first integral** of this system. To do this, I find the solution by  using standard linear algebra method and get:
\begin{gather*}
\begin{cases}
 x_0 =-C_{{0}}{{\rm e}^{t}}-C_{{1}}{{\rm e}^{-3\,t}}+C_{{2}}{{\rm e}^{-t}}+C_{{3}}{{\rm e}^{3\,t}},\\
x_{{1}}  =-\frac 1 3\,C_{{0}}{{\rm e}^{t}}+C_{{1}}{{\rm e}^{-3\,t}}-\frac 1 3\,C_{
{2}}{{\rm e}^{-t}}+C_{{3}}{{\rm e}^{3\,t}},\\
x_{{2}}  =\frac 1 3 \,C_{{0}}{{\rm e}^{t}}-C_{{1}}{{\rm e}^{-3\,t}}-\frac 1 3\,C_{{2}}{{\rm e}
^{-t}}+C_{{3}}{{\rm e}^{3\,t}},\\
x_{{3}}  =C_{{0}}{
{\rm e}^{t}}+C_{{1}}{{\rm e}^{-3\,t}}+C_{{2}}{{\rm e}^{-t}}+C_{{3}}{
{\rm e}^{3\,t}} 
\end{cases}
\end{gather*}

The first integral is a function of $x_i$ which is constant on the solution. After long and brute force ugly complicated calculations, I have finally managed to find it:
\begin{align*}
&{x_{0}}^{2}{x_{{3}}}^{2}-6\,x_{{0}}x_{{1}}x_{{2}}x_{{3}}+4\,x_{{0}}{
x_{{2}}}^{3}+4\,{x_{{1}}}^{3}x_{{3}}-3\,{x_{{1}}}^{2}{x_{{2}}}^{2} \\
&=-{\frac {64}{27}}\,{C_{{0}}}^{2}{C_{{2}}}^{2}+{\frac {256}{27}}\,{C_{{0
}}}^{3}C_{{1}}+64\,{C_{{1}}}^{2}{C_{{3}}}^{2}+{\frac {256}{27}}\,{C_{{
2}}}^{3}C_{{3}}-{\frac {128}{3}}\,C_{{0}}C_{{1}}C_{{2}}C_{{3}}
\end{align*}

I am dissatisfied with the approach  because it is too customized and cannot be applied to other systems of equations. Also, I am not sure whether there are other first integrals.

**Question.**  Is there a general method for finding the first integrals of such homogeneous systems of linear differential equations with constant coefficients?

Comment: From your solution the matrix on the right hand side looks diagonalizable. Then you can write your system as four independent first order de's.. Perhaps then take two of those de's and adapt this solution https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2902441/finding-a-first-integral-of-a-system-of-first-order-des

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The homogeneous first order system is given by $\dot{\mathbf x} = A\mathbf x$, where $A$ is given by
$$
A = \left(\begin{array}{cccc}0 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 3 & 0\end{array}\right).
$$
(I assume the "$2$" in the final equation of the system in the OP is a typo, since the stated solutions satisfy the system above.)

Now $A$ has characteristic polynomial
$
\chi_A(t) = t^4-10t^2+9 = (t^2-9)(t^2-1),
$
and hence 4 distinct eigenvalues $\{\pm 1, \pm 3\}$, so that $A$ is diagonalizable. For convenience, we will write $(\lambda_0,\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3) = (-3,-1,1,3)$ for the eigenvalues of $A$ given in increasing order. Then $\{\mathbf v_j: 0 \leq j \leq 3\}$ is a basis of eigenvectors for $A$ where
$$
\mathbf v_0 = \left(\begin{array}{c}1 \\ -1 \\ 1 \\ -1\end{array}\right),
\mathbf v_1 = \left(\begin{array}{c}3 \\ -1 \\ -1 \\ 3\end{array}\right)
\mathbf v_2 = \left(\begin{array}{c}3 \\ 1 \\ -1 \\ -3\end{array}\right),
\mathbf v_3 = \left(\begin{array}{c}1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{array}\right),
$$
and $A\mathbf v_j = \lambda_j \mathbf v_j$. The general solution to the homogeneous system of differential equations it encodes is therefore given by
$$
\mathbf x(t) = c_0e^{-3t} \mathbf v_0 + c_1 e^{-t}\mathbf{v}_1 + c_2e^t\mathbf v_2 + c_3e^{3t}\mathbf v_3, \quad c_0,c_1,c_2,c_3 \in \mathbb C.
$$

The key to obtaining first integrals of this system is then to use the coordinates given by the eigenvectors of $A$: since they form a basis of $\mathbb R^4$ we may write any vector $\mathbf v\in \mathbb R^4$ uniquely as $\sum_{j=0}^3 \alpha_j\mathbf v_j$, and the linear functionals $\alpha_j\colon \mathbb R^4 \to \mathbb R$ are just the basis of $(\mathbb R^4)^*$ dual to $\{\mathbf v_j:0\leq j \leq 3\}$. Equivalently, they are the eigenvectors of $A^\intercal$ (normalised so that $\alpha_k A \mathbf v_j = \delta_{jk}$). In our case they are thus:
$$
8\alpha_0 = (1,-3,3,-1), \quad 
8\alpha_1 = (1,-1,-1,1), \quad 
8\alpha_2 = (1,1,-1,-1), \quad
8\alpha_3 = (1,3,3,1).
$$

We may write these in notation more standard for differential equations as follows: if $\mathbf x = (x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3)^\intercal$ then
$$
\alpha_0(\mathbf x) = x_0-3x_1+3x_2+x_3, \quad \alpha_1(\mathbf x) = x_0-x_1-x_2+x_3, \\
\alpha_2(\mathbf x) = x_0+x_1-x_2-x_3, \quad \alpha_3(\mathbf x) = x_0+3x_1+3x_2+x_3.
$$

Now it is clear from the above description of the general solution of the system $\dot{\mathbf x} = A\mathbf x$ that $\dot{\alpha}_j = \frac{d\alpha_j}{dt} = \lambda_j\alpha_j$, and hence it follows that if we set, for $\mathbf d = (d_0,d_1,d_2,d_3) \in \mathbb N^4$
$$
g_\mathbf d = \alpha_0^{d_0}\alpha_1^{d_1}\alpha_2^{d_2}\alpha_3^{d_3}, 
$$
then $g_{\mathbf d}$ is an integral of the system whenever
$$
-3d_0-d_1+d_2+3d_3=0.
$$
Thus we obtain, for example, the quadratic function
$$
p_2=\alpha_1\alpha_2 = (x_0+x_1-x_2-x_3)(x_0-x_1-x_2+x_3) = x_0^2-x_1^2+x_2^2 -x_3^2 +2(x_1x_3-x_0x_2)
$$
as a first integral of the system.

In general, the polynomial functions which are first integrals of this system form a subring of $\mathbb C[x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3]$ which is generated by the set $\{p_2,q_2,p_4,q_4\}$ where $p_2=\alpha_1\alpha_2,q_2 = \alpha_0\alpha_3, p_4 = \alpha_0\alpha_2^3, q_4=\alpha_1^3\alpha_3$, two quadratic and two quartic polynomials. Thus, for example, the space of quartic first integrals is 5-dimensional spanned by $\{p_2^2,q_2^2,p_2q_2,p_4,q_4\}$, which contains the quartic obtained by the OP.

Comment: Thank you!! Nice solution

Comment: You're most welcome. Happy Christmas!

Comment: Please see my another similar question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4833921/how-can-i-eliminate-variable

Answer (score 1):

Considering the solution of
\begin{gather*}
\begin{cases}
\dot x_0=3\, x_1\\
  \dot x_1=x_0+2\, x_2,\\
 \dot x_2 =2\, x_1+  x_3,\\
 \dot x_3 =3\, x_{2}.
\end{cases}
\end{gather*}

after substituting $e^t\equiv e$ and reduction to a common denominator, we have equivalently

$$
\Phi=\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
8 e^3 x_0 -c_1 e^6-3 c_2 e^6-3 c_3 e^6-c_4 e^6-3 c_1 e^4-3 c_2 e^4+3 c_3 e^4+3 c_4 e^4-3c_1 e^2+3 c_2 e^2+3 c_3 e^2-3 c_4 e^2-c_1+3 c_2-3 c_3+c_4 = 0\\
8 e^3 x_1-c_1 e^6-3 c_2 e^6-3 c_3 e^6-c_4 e^6-c_1 e^4-c_2 e^4+c_3 e^4+c_4 e^4+c_1 e^2-c_2e^2-c_3 e^2+c_4 e^2+c_1-3 c_2+3 c_3-c_4 = 0 \\
8 e^3 x_2-c_1 e^6-3 c_2 e^6-3 c_3 e^6-c_4 e^6+c_1 e^4+c_2 e^4-c_3 e^4-c_4 e^4+c_1 e^2-c_2e^2-c_3 e^2+c_4 e^2-c_1+3 c_2-3 c_3+c_4 = 0 \\
8 e^3 x_3 -c_1 e^6-3 c_2 e^6-3 c_3 e^6-c_4 e^6+3 c_1 e^4+3 c_2 e^4-3 c_3 e^4-3 c_4 e^4-3c_1 e^2+3 c_2 e^2+3 c_3 e^2-3 c_4 e^2+c_1-3 c_2+3 c_3-c_4 = 0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

and then using the command from MATHEMATICA

```
Eliminate[Phi, e]
```

The result is too long to show here, since it involves several integrals. `Eliminate` works using Groebner basis. This procedure can be used when the system matrix $A$ in $\dot x = A x$, has multiplicative eigenvalues. In this example we have $(-3,-1,1,3)$

Comment: yes, you are right, the last equation should be  $$\dot  x_3=3 x_2.$$